# puppeteer returning undefined when trying to scrape img src

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I was trying to **scrape** a thumbnail image from youtube with its XPath but I am getting `undefined` for the src. I can't figure out what is causing this? I already tried using both the XPath and full XPath but that didn't help. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeChannel1(url) {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url, {
    timeout: 0
  });

  const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="dismissible"]/ytd-thumbnail');
  const src1 = await el2.getProperty('src');
  const thumbnailURL1 = await src1.jsonValue();

  browser.close();
  console.log({
    thumbnailURL1
  })
  return {
    thumbnailURL1
  }
}

scrapeChannel1('https://www.youtube.com/')
```

Comment: The ytd-thumbnail element is not an img element. You need to go deeper. Also not all ytd-thumbnail elements have a img within them. You should iterate them all to find the first valid one.

Comment: iterate all thumbnails? can you suggest how I can do that?@John

Comment: `for(let el of page.$$("ytd-thumbnail img"))`

Comment: you mean ```of page.$x()```@John

Comment: nope. Not using xpath. Using querySelectorAll.

Comment: then the src of the queryselector would be the src i scraped from youtube xpath?@John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<img>` you are looking for is placed a bit deeper in the DOM at: `'//*[@id="dismissible"]/ytd-thumbnail/a/yt-img-shadow/img'` (so you should add: `/a/yt-img-shadow/img` at the end of your XPath expression).
Note, you have more powerful tools in puppeteer than `.getProperty('src')` to retrieve DOM element properties.

E.g. [`page.$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v8.0.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1):

```js
const selector = 'ytd-thumbnail > a > yt-img-shadow > #img'
const imageSrc = await page.$eval(selector, el => el.src)

// returns: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{youtube_id}/hqdefault.jpg...
```

Or if you want all images use [`page.$$eval`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v8.0.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args):

```js
const imageSrcs = await page.$$eval(selector, elems => elems.map(el => el.src))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get images `src` from YouTube, you need to [scroll video thumbnails into view](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-youtube-search-video-results-with-nodejs/#code_explanation) like in the code below ([also check it on the online IDE](https://replit.com/@MikhailZub/Scrape-YouTube-main-page-thumbnails-with-NodeJS#index.js)):

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const mainPageUrl = "https://www.youtube.com";

async function scrollPage(page, scrollElements) {
  let currentElement = 0;
  while (true) {
    let elementsLength = await page.evaluate((scrollElements) => {
      return document.querySelectorAll(scrollElements).length;
    }, scrollElements);
    for (; currentElement < elementsLength; currentElement++) {
      await page.waitForTimeout(200);
      await page.evaluate(
        (currentElement, scrollElements) => {
          document.querySelectorAll(scrollElements)[currentElement].scrollIntoView();
        },
        currentElement,
        scrollElements
      );
    }
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
    let newElementsLength = await page.evaluate((scrollElements) => {
      return document.querySelectorAll(scrollElements).length;
    }, scrollElements);
    if (newElementsLength === elementsLength || currentElement > 100) break; // if you want to get all elements (or some other number of elements) change number to 'Infinity' (or some other number)
  }
}

async function getThumbnails() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(60000);
  await page.goto(mainPageUrl);
  await page.waitForSelector("#contents");
  const scrollElements = "a#thumbnail";
  await scrollPage(page, scrollElements);
  await page.waitForTimeout(10000);
  const urls = await page.$$eval("a#thumbnail #img", (els) => els.map(el => el.getAttribute('src')).filter(el => el));
  await browser.close();
  return urls;
}

getThumbnails().then(console.log);
```

Output

```json
[
   "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/02oeySm1CJA/hq720.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCNAFEJQDSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLBmrYMHESpY_f1oTNx00iuR3tNeCQ",
   "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RMo2haIPYBM/hq720_live.jpg?sqp=CNifxJcG-oaymwEcCNAFEJQDSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLBw4ogzR0709SqbttRdEzfL-aTdgQ",
   "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/qJFFp_ta1Zk/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCOADEI4CSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLBJ-44OFgBUuVUYWBVh3Yi3hQgwIg",
   "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/OZoTjoN-Sn0/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCOADEI4CSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLCOeGTCnlT4U0wV1SNclkmFUEHLaA",
   "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/L8cH2gI67uk/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCOADEI4CSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLAuvZ3khIjpvAVTGjmR9FDxQrPIgQ",
   "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/6rUyVKyJnGY/hq720.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCNAFEJQDSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLCifsTG4MlA3mf8CcJDkfKdWaZkaA",
   "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xpaURivPZFk/hq720_2.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEdCJYDENAFSFXyq4qpAw8IARUAAIhCcAHAAQbQAQE=&rs=AOn4CLA5oFDDsVzbV3tUqyfogfuf3LPahQ",
   "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/MsR76PyVdUs/hq720_2.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEdCJYDENAFSFXyq4qpAw8IARUAAIhCcAHAAQbQAQE=&rs=AOn4CLAEBYGNvif-7LWx2mqW4G9o-OUhEQ",
   "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/liasQRRVt5w/hq720_2.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEdCJYDENAFSFXyq4qpAw8IARUAAIhCcAHAAQbQAQE=&rs=AOn4CLAUcMpyKY0GhmNAHHtP_cDkAp18DQ",
   "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Dr5IqlTLMDM/hq720_2.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEdCJYDENAFSFXyq4qpAw8IARUAAIhCcAHAAQbQAQE=&rs=AOn4CLBOSUi6mgjdD5a-Jx8Ns24SlexB1g",
   "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E8kit8xJKdI/hq720_2.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEdCJYDENAFSFXyq4qpAw8IARUAAIhCcAHAAQbQAQE=&rs=AOn4CLDDStn95G7ei5DTusGXE4RimzdLUw",
   "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SqEaahOmLHU/hq720_2.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEdCM0CENAFSFXyq4qpAw8IARUAAIhCcAHAAQbQAQE=&rs=AOn4CLBDcWLCklNxEAuT1ZvSTKrIplGOag",
    ...and other results
]
```

You can read more about scraping YouTube search from my blog post [Web scraping YouTube search video results with Nodejs](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-youtube-search-video-results-with-nodejs/).